# How to show processing bar on register info through cloud firestore with flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to show processing bar after button gets clicked.
First of all, 
I took a variable `isLoading` with `bool` type and initialized with `false` then created a custom processing bar with Condition, means
if is isLoading is true then show `CircularProgressIndicator()`, if it's
false then show Container().

this is my code, which I had tried but it's not working.
perhaps I'm doing in wrong way.

```
registerInfo(){
    setState(() {
      isLoading=true; 
    });
    if (firstAndLastNameController.text.isNotEmpty &&
          emailController.text.isNotEmpty &&
          birthDateController.text.isNotEmpty &&
          addressController.text.isNotEmpty 
          ) {
          Firestore.instance
          .collection('Users')
          .document(uid)
          .setData({
            "FullName": firstAndLastNameController.text,
            "Email": emailController.text,
            "BirthDate": birthDateController.text,
            "Address":addressController.text
        })  
        .then((result) => {

          firstAndLastNameController.clear(),
          emailController.clear(),
          birthDateController.clear(),
          addressController.clear(),
          Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Information successfully resgistered", backgroundColor: Colors.green)

        }).catchError((err) => print(err));
       setState(() {
        isLoading=false; 
       });

    }else{
      setState(() {
       isLoading=false; 
      });
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Please, fill all fields", backgroundColor: Colors.red);
    }

  }
```

Custom progressing bar

```
 Positioned( //Custom progressing bar
            child: isLoading
            ?Container(
            color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8),
             child: Center(
                child: Container(
                height: 100.0,
                width: 100.0,
               decoration: BoxDecoration(
                 color: Colors.white,
                 borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)
               ),
                child: Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),  
                ),

              ),
              ),
            )
            :Container()
          )
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by *it's not working*.

Comment: I mean progressing bar is not working

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you are trying to do I recommend using a FutureBuilder Widget.

With the FutureBuilder Widget you can show some content while the request is loading and show a different content when the Future resolves. Thats in the case of a Stateless Widget,
but in your case i see that you are using a Stateful Widget so you would just need to place the setState call from inside the 'then' method. Hope it helps :)

Comment: I tried to inside from then() method but  setState() doesn't exist.means , then() method is not allowing me to call  setState() from there.

Comment: I was gonna also suggest awaiting then Setting State but you already got the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code in `build()` method:-

```
Container(
     child: !isLoading
            ? Container()//Here add your main container
            : Center(
                 child: const CircularProgressIndicator(
                        valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                                    Color(colorPrimary))),
                    ),
)
```

Comment: you didn't get it, I mean, already created processing bar,  just want to show in resgisterInfo() method.

Comment: Ok, Then you can you async and await.